# Are commands supposed to do "nothing" in some cases

Tags: command, naming-conventions

In my opinion there basically exist two different methods:
commands and gets (queries) voids and returns.

I often encounter following situation:
A void method (command) is called. When I see the implementaion, I notice
that this method not always actually does something depending on some special conditions or something.

Consider this example:

```
caller.NotifyCustomer();


NotifyCustomer()
{
  if(weather.IsNice || moon.IsShining)
  {
    return;
  }

  Notify();
}
```

My problem with code like this is that the caller obviously has a clear intention: He wants to notify a customer.
But the method itself does not always actually notify the customer.
In my opinion this is confusing. I would not expect this behaviour by just reading the method name.
I could rename the method to somewhat like `NotifyCustomerIfApplicable`
but this does not seem to be very handsome either.
Another option would be to check for those special conditions before calling the actual method `NotifyCustomer()`, by extracting the if evaluation in a seperated method that can be called before.
But this isn't really nice either I guess.

Is there a clear recommendation?

Comment: There are actually two methods here: (a) the one that checks for the conditions and (b) the actual notification. Implement both and call (b) only when (a) is true.

Comment: okay so you would agree with me there? This is basically what I ment with 'Another option would be to check for those special conditions before calling the actual method NotifyCustomer(), by extracting the if evaluation in a seperated method that can be called before.'

Comment: I do agree with you. Moreover I suggest moving the condition checking to a method, say `ShouldNotifyCustomer`, so that the clients will only need to call it before deciding to issue a notification. This would avoid clients from having to work on the details of the check, while allowing them to better express their intention.